# Lenovo g480 SSD appears and disappears randomly

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop, samsung-ssd

I have Lenovo g480 and its specs:

I5-3210m, 8gb ram, Nividia gt610m, Samsung Evo 870 SSD, 650gb HDD

I have win 10 installed on the whole SSD in UEFI mode the problem was when the laptop shutdown improperly such as when the battery becomes empty or pressing power button to force its shutdown the SSD becomes not detected in bios and it shows boot menu without it , when I tries to boot to windows iso or hiren's bootcd the SSD is also disappeared but the strange thing is when I leave it for sometime it boots normally at first the time was half an hour then becomes 2 hours then becomes 6 hours now it can last up for a day then the SSD is detected again

But unfortunately now even when I shutdown the windows properly it disappears

The SSD is now in the place of HDD and the HDD is in a DVD caddy I tried to replace their places , to take off HDD and boot from SSD only and there is no difference and after while it boots normally again!!

I noticed when I boot from anything windows or Linux iso and it just boots then turn off the laptop the SSD is immediately shown up and boots normally

I have also a bios problem that I can't enter it by f2 or novo button or in the boot menu there was an option when I press tab for bios menu it disappears I talked about that problem in details in another question and its link is

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Laptops/Can-t-enter-bios-Lenovo-g480/m-p/5221009

Now what is the reason for that weird problem and is the bios problem can be the cause of it I have been two years can't use my laptop for some time normally.

I will attach a video while the laptop in that case and I am sorry if the question is too long but I said everything in details to have a better assistant

Comment: Temporarily remove the SSD, put the HDD back in, install Windows and see if it runs normally. If so, that means the SSD probably has hardware errors.

Comment: @John And the bios problem isn't related to that problem ?

Comment: And what will be the reason for that problem of SSD ?

Comment: *"And what will be the reason for that problem of SSD ?"* making a habit of switching its power off without unmounting properly.

Comment: That wasn't a habit it becomes by chance if the battery goes empty and it wasn't on charger or windows get stuck and I have to switch if off by force

Comment: Ensure that the laptop is well-grounded electrically, possibly with a metallic wire to a pipe.

Comment: And the bios problem isn't related to that problem ? –   ..... I have replaced Hard Drives with Samsung SSDs and BIOS was the same throughout.